# Database Structure for a Faceted Search

Tags: database-design, data-structures, entity-attribute-value, faceted-search, categorization

I am creating an eCommerce site that needs to have a faceted search tool so that customers can narrow down a product search via categories and classifications in the same style as [ebuyer.com](http://www.ebuyer.com/search?page=1&store=5&cat=10&mfr=3) and [Newegg.com](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100006740%2050001186&IsNodeId=1&name=Hewlett-Packard) (See left hand menus).

I initially dived straight into designing a database that ended up similar to an EAV structure (I didn't know what this was at the time), this initially seemed ideal as I could create unlimited categories, subcategories and other product classifications (i.e. Colour, Size, Recipient) that customers could use to find specific products. However, when I started trying to create SQL queries using `AND` conditions, I realised how normal simple queries became much longer and complex to write.

After spending a few hours reading through various posts on SO and articles on Google, I've come to realise the nightmare that would lye ahead if I continued with this method.

**Question**

How have sites like [ebuyer.com](http://www.ebuyer.com/search?page=1&store=5&cat=10&mfr=3) and [Newegg.com](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100006740%2050001186&IsNodeId=1&name=Hewlett-Packard) designed their faceted search?

Have I missed an alternative method or have they simply gone ahead with an EAV structure?
I'm looking to avoid enterprise solutions like Lucene/Solr.

Answer (score 3):

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/PublicServers

Ebuyer uses solr and for good reason, you risk reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how they do it but you can achieve this by doing:

```
CREATE TABLE  product_facets (
  product_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  facet VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  facet_value varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (product_id,facet,facet_value),
  KEY (facet,facet_value)
);

INSERT INTO product_facets VALUES (1, 'COLOR', 'Red');
INSERT INTO product_facets VALUES (1, 'PRICE_RANGE', 'Less than 200');

INSERT INTO product_facets VALUES (2, 'COLOR', 'Green');
INSERT INTO product_facets VALUES (2, 'PRICE_RANGE', 'From $200 to $500');

INSERT INTO product_facets VALUES (2, 'COLOR', 'Blue');
INSERT INTO product_facets VALUES (3, 'PRICE_RANGE', 'More than $1000');

SELECT facet, facet_value, count(*)
FROM   product_facets f
INNER  JOIN products p ON p.product_id = f.product_id
GROUP BY facet, facet_value;
```

**facet** doesn't have to be VARCHAR. It can be a simple INTEGER as your application knows what it means.

Answer (score 1):

Well why do you call Lucene/Solr entreprise wise solution... seems to fit perfectly your need in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mixing different concepts (which in turn may make it more difficult to find a solution).

Faceted search means basically *filtering by* a specific quality of the "item". That quality or property may be a category it is in, or it may be something else.

You could have a faceted search of users where you filter by their age, for example

```
[    User   ]
| name char |
| age  int  |
```

How you adjust Solr (or Sphinx) to get the end result might vary, but it has no influence in your data model.

I would start by conceptualizing/modeling what you're trying to represent/store in the database. How you display it or search it comes later.

Without more details, your question about how other sites `designed their faceted search` is too broad, and at the same time very simple: you just need to generate the different facets based on the different properties of the products; but you also seem to want to know how they have modeled their database to store the information.